# Salesforce URL hacking not working for Lookup field

Tags: apex, url, urlhacking

On Contact I have one custom button where we want to give create opportunity functionality. It is working fine for most of the values but not able to populate the look up field. I tried below ways.

```
/lightning/o/opportunity/new?useRecordTypeCheck=1&nooverride=true&defaultFieldValues=Contact__c={!Contact.Id},
Name={!Contact.name}
```

Here Contact__c is the the lookup field of which label name Primary Contact ( API name Contact__c)

[image]

I tried below steps also but not working..

```
1) Right click on lookup field (not on lookup icon) and inspect element.
2) Copy the id of field. Now you have field id.
3) Put field id = '' in URL,  try without space.
5) Now you can see that the value will be visible in lookup field.
```

Comment: Why not use an action instead of url hacking?

Comment: What happens if you change it Name instead of name

Comment: Buisness want to use URL hacking only as they already have lots of URL hacking working already. this is first time we are trying for lookup fields.

Comment: @Guest Name already  working but lookup is not working. Contact__c={!Contact.Id}

Comment: Just to confirm, is the contact field you're trying to populate a custom lookup rather than a renaming of the standard Contact field on Opportunity?

Comment: yes it's custom

Comment: @CallumMacErlich Hi Callum if we change it to standard will that work. or any workaround if you can please suggest.

Answer (score -1):

This is working for me I had the custom field name as Opportunity_Contact__c instead of Contact__c

```
/lightning/o/opportunity/new?useRecordTypeCheck=1&nooverride=true&defaultFieldValues=Opportunity_Contact__c={!Contact.Id},
Name={!Contact.Name}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. As is, this isn't a very useful answer because it amounts to "It works in my org". There's nothing here that the OP (or other people visiting this question) can do to know if this will or won't be an issue for them, nor anything about why this issue occurs and how to fix it.

Comment: If you have performed some research into this issue (to identify what the issue is and when it happens) and have a solution for the issue, then please [edit] your answer to add that information. Otherwise, the appropriate answer here is "Use an action instead of URL hacking" and "**Don't let your non-technical stakeholders dictate how to solve a problem**". Stakeholders describe _what_ they want to have, not _how_ to achieve it.